# regex to filter sentences with minimum word lengths

Tags: javascript, regex

I cant seem to find a regular expression to filter sentences with word lengths less than 'n' characters.

Example: 'n' = 3

"Hello World, Hello Again" is no match

"Hello World, Javascript is Crazy" is a match because 'is' has less than 3 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[11:42:43.562] /\b\w{1,2}\b/.test("Hello World, Hello Again")
[11:42:43.565] false
--
[11:43:09.002] /\b\w{1,2}\b/.test("Hello World, Javascript is Crazy")
[11:43:09.005] true
```

Use {1,2} if you want less than, use {1,3} if you want less than or equal.

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
var pattern = '/\b.{1,3}\b/';
```